# Can django-celery be used for normal AJAX calls?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I am going through Celery (Django_celery) documentation.

I have one confusion. Can it be used for normal AJAX calls?

Example: lets say I have a button similar to 'Like' button on facebook. Is celery suitable for that Like 'task'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not really. Celery is for asynchronous backend tasks - Ajax is asynchronous in the sense that the Javascript doesn't block while waiting for a response, but in other respects it's just like a normal request: you make a call to a URL, which returns a response via HTTP.

Celery doesn't do that: it's useful for kicking off long-running backend jobs, but can't really return a response at the end of them. Where it might be useful is if you had a view that was called by your Ajax which kicked off a Celery job, and then your JS would ping it periodically to see if it was finished, and update your HTML accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Keeping in mind the answer, and taking facebook as an example yet again, can I use: 
- Celery to calculate 'user's mutual friends and store them in a DB table' at some point during night so that when user wants to view them on UI, I just query that table and **show** result. 
- CAN NOT/SHOULD NOT use Celery to **calculate** and **show** 'user's mutual friends' list at run time when a user clicks a button on UI? Do a call to a normal view at this point and return result. 
Let me know if I am going in the right direction :)

Comment: Well, you could do the first one, if it wasn't strictly forbidden by Facebook's terms and conditions (they restrict the sorts of data you can store). And yes, the second one is not appropriate for Celery.

Comment: can't upvote because I do not have enough reputation :( but marking did work.